# Input data to Maxent niche modelling tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-formats, ascii, esri-ascii-raster, maxent

I have following question regarding the input format of files to [**Maxent**](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~schapire/maxent/).

From **[here](http://www.worldclim.org/)** I downloaded the environmental layers but they are in tiff format and I guess the tool needs in asc format where number of columns,rows etc and something like a matrix is there.  How do I get the exact format required by the tool?

How do I solve it.

Comment: Is [**this**](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~schapire/maxent/) the **Maxent** that you are using?

Comment: @PolyGeo yes i am using maxent

Comment: @PolyGeo yes i downloaded from the same site

Comment: My advice on this one is to focus on one question at a time - the Q & A format of GIS SE works best when only one question is asked per Question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The worldclim data is in Geotiff format and Maxent uses ASCII files in ESRI .asc format. The conversion should be relatively simple. If you have access to ArcGIS, you can load the Geotiff and export it using the ["Raster to ASCII" tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000005000000)

If you use QGIS then load the raster, go to Raster -> Conversion -> Translate -> as file type choose Arc/Info ASCII Grid (.ASC)

Comment: This did not work. It exports as .txt.

Comment: @user104440 an ASCII file *is* a text file.  If it has output as `.txt` then change the file extension to `.asc`